# bash script returns that user exists but user does not exist

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

**PLEASE TAKE NOTE OF THE REMARK IN THE CODE AFTER FI!**
For the creation of a user account via the browser i let php shell_exec execute a bash script. Even though i'm certain (by checking /etc/shadow) that the username is not taken the script says it does.
The script as it is now does execute the useradd command and the username appears in the /etc/shadow.
Looks like it executes the useradd before and then checks if the user exists?

php

```
$command = "sudo ./createclientcert.sh $userName $userPass";
if(shell_exec("$command echo $?") == 0){
echo 1;
}
```

Shellscript

```
#!/bin/bash

newclient () {
getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo $?
else
useradd $1
echo $1:$2 | chpasswd   
fi
# PLEASE TAKE NOTE!! funny thing is that when code (that had nothing to do with the account creation and was to be removed) that came after fi is in place it works well. 
}

newclient "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: `getent passwd $1 > /dev/null 2&>1` may not be correct. It should've been `getent passwd $1 >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Also, shouldn't `shell_exec("$comm echo $?")` have been `shell_exec("$command echo $?")` ??

Comment: @sjsam $comm was typo. Sorry for that. indeed 2&>1 should be 2>&1 when i googlecheck quickly  but i copied and pasted it from another post.

Comment: It looks a bit strange. What do you expect the final output should be? What is the actual output? What does "the script says it does" mean?

Comment: It says the user exists $? = 0 and tgen does create the account which it days that exists. But see the answer that i posted myself because i think it's something that's not reproducible.

Comment: `"$command echo $?" `  executes `./createclientcert.sh` with 4 parameters (`$userName $userPass echo $?`). You handle the exit codes `$?` in a complicated way managing an stdout output, which is implicitly converted to PHP integer compared with 0. Just use PHP `system()` and terminate your shell script with a propper exit code.

Comment: Pff... could you please show me how to given my code provided? :-)

Comment: Ok, I've created (and edited) an answer. I could not try adding a user yet, but should work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if useradd "$1" >/dev/null ; then
    echo $1:$2 | chpasswd >/dev/null
    # user created
    exitcode=0
else
    # user already exists
    exitcode=1
fi

# do stuff regardless if user created or not
7z a /var/www/html/download/$1.zip /var/www/html/download/$1.ovpn

# the script would exit with the exit code of latest executed command
# if you dont explicitly give another exit code:
exit $exitcode
```

PHP

```
$output = system("sudo ./createclientcert.sh \"$userName\" \"$userPass\"", $exitcode);

switch($exitcode)
{
  case 0:
    echo "User created."
    break;
  case 1:
    echo "User already exists.";
    break;
}
```

Comment: :-) THNX! Edites this peace of php '$output = system("sudo ./cert.sh $userName $userPass $exitcode");' and it now works as it should. I'm very thankful!

Comment: Sorry. I was too fast. It doesn't work. I'm investigating.

Comment: What is your current script? Have you tried the shell script above?

Comment: yes i did. I'm now trying all kind of things byr i'm getting the impression that getent is talking nonsense. I wished there was another way of checking if a username is in use.

Comment: I did not utilize `getent` in my answer. There is nothing else than `if useradd ...`. It will not do anything and return a non-zero exit code, when the user already exists. Thus the else branch will be executed.

Comment: Don't what went wrong yesterday but i must have suffert some strange blindness or so. Your code works! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Keep things simple. ;-) NOTE: I'm not sure, about the line `echo $1:$2 | chpasswd >/dev/null` taken from your code. It could raise a problem when an argument contains whitespaces. Maybe it has to be enclosed into escaped quotes(?)

Comment: Ok no... I think simulating keyboard inputs won't result in such a problem. The backdraw is only, a command line (the echo) could be read out via process lists or histories. Maybe you find another more secure method of changing the password.

Comment: The problem was mainly in the idea that i had to do something with the outcome of the bash to echo it back to the requesting client (ajax). But the echo from the bash is also an echo in php. A bit stupid from me perhaps. I'm very thankful for you supplying me the answer.

Comment: The password change is to circumvent setting a password non-interactively. The account serve only the clients obtaining a VPN. There's no data attached to those account. It's for an extra layer of auth and enables me to use the same certificates for all clients.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output when you run this on the system?

```
getent passwd [username]
```

It is possible that a record for this user exists in one of the following, as getent searches these locations, not only `/etc/shadow`:

> The databases it searches in are: ahosts, ahostsv4, ahostsv6, aliases, ethers (Ethernet addresses), group, gshadow, hosts, netgroup, networks, passwd, protocols, rpc, services, and shadow.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent

Try to remove the user:

```
userdel -r [username]
```

where `-r` will remove all of the user's files along with the user itself.
After that try running the PHP script again.

Comment: It's not a production machine with lots of users or so. So the fact that i'm certain that a given username does not exists is based on that.

Comment: And i checked it by issuing it via the terminal.  Entering 'getent passwd jajaja' it jumps to the other line with no output. User jajaja obviously is a made up nonexistent username. :) And take note of the remark that when other code is in place it all executes well. A bizar thing given the fact that the code had nothing to do with user account creation but had a delaying effect or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer but it works leaving the stupid 7z in place. Bizar!!

```
#!/bin/bash

newclient () {
getent passwd $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo $?
else
useradd -p encrypted_password $1
#useradd $1
echo $1:$2 | chpasswd   
fi
# if i remove the following line or comment it out the script starts  malfunctioning
7z a /var/www/html/download/$1.zip /var/www/html/download/$1.ovpn 
}

newclient "$1" "$2"
```